# How to structure python project for use with coverage.py?

Tags: python, setup.py, coverage.py

I have a package with the following layout:

```
tiny-py-interpreter/
|-- setup.py
|-- .coveragerc
|-- tinypy/
    | -- foo/
    | -- bar/
    | -- tests/
    | -- tinypyapp.py
    | -- run_tests.py
```

Here are some lines from the setup.py:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points = {
        'console_scripts' : [ 'tinypy = tinypy.tinypyapp:main']
    },
    test_suite = 'tinypy.run_tests.get_suite',
)
```

After installing the package a console script called `tinypy` is installed:

```
pip3 install .
```

Then I run coverage:

```
coverage run setup.py test
coverage combine
coverage report
```

All the tests I have are implemented in a such way that each test launches a subprocess of the `tinypy`, so I use `parallel = True` in `.coveragerc` to capture the result of the coverage run.

Essentially, I have the same layout as `coverage` [itself](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/master/coverage/cmdline.py), where `coverage` and `cmdline.py` are the same things as `tinypy` and `tinypyapp.py` in my case.

**The problem**: when console script `tinypy` (`tinypyapp.py`) is executed, it uses an installed version of the `tinypy` package, which is located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tinypy/`. Coverage ignores sources in `./tinypy` (as they're not used). If `source` parameter is omitted, that it's possible to see coverage for the code from `site-packages/tinypy`.

**The question**: how to structure the project properly? When `tinypyapp.py` is installed as a script, it is installed on the same level as `tinypy` folder (one level higher, not inside). I can't place `tinypyapp.py` outside the `tinypy` folder, as then setup.py can't find it. Because of this I can't use `tinypyapp.py` and have to use name of the script (which is `tinypy`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest thing would be to not install the code you are working on into site-packages, but instead to use a development install:

```
pip install -e .
```

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is to create `test_entry_point.py` in the root folder:

```
tiny-py-interpreter/
|-- setup.py
|-- test_entry_point.py
|-- ...
```

With the following content:

```
import sys
from tinypy.tinypyapp import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And use the following filename when launching a subprocess in test:

```
tinypy_binary = sys.executable + ' ' + os.getcwd() + '/test_entryp.py'
subprocess.run(tinypy_binary, ...)
```